# 3D array needed from SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, multidimensional-array

I have a site with graphs that are populated by rows returned by a SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM datatable WHERE userId = $userId;
```

Now I have a portion of my site where I wish to display many graphs on one page. So given a list of userId's, I need to query the DB for their corresponding rows.

This response will be sent back to the client via JSON and plotted. Ideally, there is a way to get back some form of 3d array from mysql. This way I wouldn't have to parse and separate the rows into an array of arrays manually.

i.e. this is what I do NOT want:

```
SELECT * FROM datatable WHERE userId IN ($userIds);   

-------------------------
| userId  |  data...    |
-------------------------
|    1    |     11      |
|    1    |     12      |
|    1    |     13      |
|    2    |     21      |
|    2    |     22      |
-------------------------
```

as it would require me to further process all the `userId == ...` into their own arrays, before returning (which seems slow and bad).

Currently I am just running the above query for each userId pushing them to an array manually, but I have heard that in general, 1 big query is significantly faster than many small ones.

Btw, I am using Laravel 4.2 and PHP 5.3 and am fetching results with:

```
$stmt = $this->DB->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: use FIND_IN_SET instead of IN

Comment: If you're using PDO I hope you're using prepared statements. Seeing variables embedded in your query is never encouraging.

Comment: No. That's the way to do it. Except you have 1+ n queries here. You only need one!  (Plus the usual caveats about prepared statements). And definitely do NOT use FIND_IN_SET.

Comment: yes I am using prepared statements, this is just simplified for SO. @Strawberry, you say "thats the way to do it". Are you referring to `WHERE userId IN ($userIds)` and lumping the rows together manually?

Comment: Yes. Your query is fine. But I don't think you're preparing your statement correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a real solution to this. Ended up having to do the grouping in code.

P.S. I see why the comments were concerned about my prepared statements, but in my actual code it looked like this.

```
$userIDs = [1, 2, 3, 4, ...]

// $placeholder = "?,?,?,?"
$placeholder = create_placeholder($userIDs);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE userID IN ($placeholder)";

$stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($userIDs);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Open to suggestions on a better way to prepare statements with an `IN` clause. But honestly people have a little faith.